# Ember losing active trail

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-router

Hi I have the following Routes in ember:

```
App.Router.map(function(){

    this.resource('meat', function() {
        this.resource('poultry', function() {
            this.route('chicken');
            this.route('duck');
        });
    });
});
```

My templates look like this:

```
<script type='text/x-handlebars' id='meat'>       
     <div>{{outlet}}</div>
</script>


<script type='text/x-handlebars' id='poultry'>
       Poultry
       <br/><br/>
          {{#link-to 'poultry.chicken'}}Chicken{{/link-to}}
          {{#link-to 'poultry.duck'}}Duck{{/link-to}}

      <br/><br/>
      <div>
         {{outlet}}
      </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="poultry/chicken">
    <h4>Chicken</h4>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="poultry/duck">
    <h4>Duck</h4>
</script>
```

The problem is, when I click on the 'Duck' link, I lose my active trail to 'Poultry'.

I can't figure it out, the path is correct, but the active classes are gone.

Here is a jsbin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yularepare/2/

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in your comment is a little different than the JSBin. You didn't include the application template. Here it is:

```
<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='application'>
  {{#link-to 'poultry.chicken' }}Poultry{{/link-to}}  

  <br/><br/>
  <div>
    {{outlet}}
  </div>
</script>
```

You're losing the `active` class because you're linking straight to `'poultry.chicken'`, not `'poultry'`. It isn't a parent route, but a sibling route. If you want to keep the active class, change you `link-to` to:

`{{#link-to 'poultry'}}Poultry{{/link-to}}`

and it should work fine. Working JSBin: http://jsbin.com/fefucalaqi/1/edit

EDIT: comment asked how to handle redirect to first result. Adding here.

```
App.PoultryIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function() {
    // write some code to get to your first result here.
    this.transitionTo('poultry.chicken');
  }
});
```

Now you'll get both: active class on all poultry routes and you'll show the first one if none were selected.

Comment: Your 18 sec faster :) i delete my answer :)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. The reason I link directly to 'Chicken' is because I want the user to see the first entry ('Chicken') immediately when he clicks on Poultry, so that there is some immediate content without having to click twice - if that makes sense! Thanks

Comment: It does make sense, but you'll have to add a redirect to poultry.index if you want both (show default and keep active) to work.

Comment: Thanks, How would I go about doing that? Apologies, I'm just starting off with Ember and even simple tasks are a bit of a challenge!